# Uploading Files With VueJS and Axios

Tags: file, vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, axios

I need to upload a file to the server in the "/assets/img" folder.
I wrote the following code, as in the example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>File
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" ref="file" 
            v-on:change="handleFileUpload($event)"
        />
    </label>
    <button v-on:click="submitFile($event)">Submit File</button>
</div>


data: function(){
    return {
        file: '',
    }
},
methods: {
    handleFileUpload: function($event){
        this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
        console.log(this.file);
    },
    submitFile: function($event){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.file);

        axios.post( 'http://uquest.name/assets/img',
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }
        ).then(function(){
            console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        })
        .catch(function(){
            console.log('FAILURE!!');
        });

        this.files = '';
    }
}
```

But the downloaded file does not appear in the "/assets/img" folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `http://uquest.name/assets/img` an api route?

Comment: no, http://uquest.name/assets/img  is just the URL path to the folder where I want to put / move the downloaded file from my <input>

Comment: There is no way no update a file from this way

Comment: Not sure I understand. 
How can I implement the functionality I need?

Instead of the URL path to the folder  http://uquest.name/assets/img I should specify a file PHP in which there should be something?

What is meant?